# TransactionScope fails check constraint

Tags: c#, sql-server, transactionscope, check-constraints

I am having a issue using TransactionScope and a check constraint in SQL Server.

I want to insert into the table as such:

```
Col A | Col B
------------
 Dave |  0
 Fred |  1
```

The table has a check constraint that there must always be an entry in Col B with '0'. The first row is inserting fine but the second row fails the constraint.

```
command.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO MyTable (ColA, ColB) VALUES(@ColA, @ColB)";                                   

            foreach (var row in model.Rows)
            {

                    command.Parameters["@ColA"].Value = model.ColA;
                    command.Parameters["@ColB"].Value = model.ColB;

                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            }
```

The check constraint calls the following function

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE ColB = 0) RETURN 1

RETURN 0
```

Could this be because the constraint is only looking at committed data and if so how can it be told to look at uncommitted data as well

Comment: Without being able to see the definition for the constraint, it's not really possible to tell what's happening.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever was just adding.

Comment: Why the `CHECK` calls a function for such a simple thing? The constraint should be defined simply as **colB=0**.

Comment: A more interesting question could be why to even have ColB when it will always have the very same value of 0? Can it be removed altogether?

Comment: @Alejandro I think the constraint is supposed to check all data, not the single row.

Comment: @DasDave Can you add the constraint definition to the question, and not just the function that the constraint calls?

Comment: @Maarten Sure, constraints always apply to every single row in the table. That's my point, if every single row must always have the very same value in ColB, why ColB has to exists to begin with?

Comment: @Alejandro I do not know the reason for the constraint to exist, but the constraint function checks that there is a minimum of 1 row where the column B value is 0. Not every row, a single row. So the column B does have a reason the exist since the value 0 can shift between rows, as long as there is at least 1 where the value is 0.

Comment: Is the constraint meant to be "If there are any rows in this table, exactly one of them must have a colB value of 0" or "..., at least one of them must have a colB value of 0", or something else?

Comment: Obviously my example is simplified for not wanting to post production code. My overall questions is still can that function access the uncommitted data?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Check Constraints are suitable for a scenario like yours.You should use a instead of update/insert [trigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx) to check that there's at least one row (in the table and /or in inserted values)

You have a inserted table in a trigger that contains all the rows that will be inserted so you can write something like this :

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM mytable a UNION inserted WHERE ColB = 0) RIASEERROR("At least one row with ColB=0 should exist")
```